# Play Framework custom validation errors with multiple String parameters

Tags: java, validation, playframework, message

I'm trying to set a custom validation error with multiple params in Play!, but it seems like my validation parameters are not rendered correctly.

I have defined in `messages`:

```
validation.customerror=This is first param "%s", and this is the second "%s"
```

The in my code I execute:

```
validation.addError("","validation.customerror", "FIRST", "SECOND");
```

And I get:

```
This is first param "", and this is the second "FIRST"
```

instead of

```
This is first param "FIRST", and this is the second "SECOND"
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your validation message with index numbers like this:

```
validation.customerror=This is first param "%1$s", and this is the second "%2$s"
```

Take a look at [Play Framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide12#aParameterisedmessagesa) for more information.